# clustering verifying two basic invariance properties

Tags: clustering, bootstrap, algorithms

disclaimer: I already asked something similar on stack overflow, but it seems to be a better place for that question here.

I recently became interested in axiomatic definitions of clustering, cf. work of

- Kleinberg : http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/LT17.pdf
- Ben-David : http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2010_1307.pdf

I have a first question/remark, in Ben-David et al. they define the property of locality (intuitively, k-cluster a first time, take a subset of k' <= k clusters, cluster their data, you recover the k' clusters from the initial clutering) and say that linkages (single, average, complete) verify this property. To me, the fact that these clustering are not permutation invariant should prevent locality (if two or more clusters are at the same distance while building the dendrogram, different dendrograms can be obtained. Also, how is done the k-cut, constant height cut?).

Second question, are you aware of a clustering algorithm whose output is:

- permutation of the N data points invariant
- "bootstrap" perturbation in the T features invariant, for T big enough

Any idea?

Comment: Check this paper: - Batyrshin I., Rudas T. Invariant Hierarchical Clustering Schemes. In: [Batyrshin, I.; Kacprzyk, J.; Sheremetov, L.; Zadeh, L.A. (Eds.). *Perception-based Data Mining and Decision Making in Economics and Finance. Series: Studies in Computational Intelligence*, vol. 36. 2007, 181-206, Springer.](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-36247-0)